# Jersey 2.7: plug subresources with web fragments

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I'm developing an application which depends from a core library and can have several modules, as web fragments. The application runs on Tomcat and exposes Jersey 2.7 WS.

In the core library there is the application definition, along with several (core) resources in a dedicated package:

```
@ApplicationPath("/a/*")
public class MyWSApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyWSApplication() {

        packages("com.example.ws.resources");
        register(JacksonFeature.class);
        register(ExceptionListener.class);
    }

}
```

Now, let say there are two core resource defined in the core library:

- `users`
- `items`

Mapped at paths

- `/users`:  all the users
- `/users/{id_user}`:  a specific user
- `/items`: all the items
- `/items/{id_item}`:  a specific item
- `/users/{id_user}/items`: items pertaining a specific user, mapped using resource locators.

Everything works as expected.

My doubt is: how can I define new subresources under `/users/{id_user}` in an optional web fragment?

To be clear, I want define a `opt_res` resource mapped under the paths:

- `/opt_res`: to get the `opt_res` alone
- `/users/{id_user}/opt_res`: to get the user related `opt_res`

Moreover, `opt_res` has to have subresources.

So, hitting the paths `<host>/a/opt_res` or `<host>/a/users/{id_user}/opt_res` should give me a `HTTP/404` if the web fragment is not installed, the subresource if it is.

Comment: So, what is your question: do you want to know how to create a subresource or do you want to know how to control how the web fragment is installed? When you will instantiate the `opt_res` web subresource IN the web resource `/users`, I suppose you will make it automatically available, so you will have to check manually before returning the subresource whether your web fragment is installed.

Comment: I know how to create subresources and I already did it in the "main application" web fragment. The problem is how to register new subresources defined inside an "optional plugin" web fragment.

Comment: The plugin will have the rest resources in a package with the name `com.example.ws.resources.fragment` and you simply add it in `MyWSApplication` using the `packages("com.example.ws.resources.fragment")` method. If the Jersey will find the package, it will work, if not, HTTPStatus 404 will be returned.